# Displaying custom objects in ArrayAdapter - the easy way?

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I am trying to display a list of Bluetooth devices in an `ArrayAdapter`, and want to override the default functionality of the adapter to show the objects `toString()`. I know that there are solutions that extend the `getView(...)` method, but I really feel this is over-complicating things. All I want is to override how the string to display is built. For Bluetooth devices this would be using `getName()` instead of `toString()`.

So I've created a custom arrayadapter like below, and would ideally have a method that is something like the `getDisplayString(T value)`

```
public class MyArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<BluetoothDevice> {
    ...
    @Override //I wish something like this existed
    protected String getDisplayString(BluetoothDevice b) {
        return b.getName();
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Altering the behavior of `getView` doesn't have to be that complicated.

```
mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<MyType>(this, R.layout.listitem, new ArrayList<MyType>()) {
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView view = (TextView) super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        // Replace text with my own
        view.setText(getItem(position).getName());
        return view;
    }
};
```

This has the disadvantage of setting the view's text twice (once in `super.getView` and once in the override) above, but that doesn't cost much. The alternative is to create the view yourself using an inflater if `convertView` isn't there.

Comment: After much hunting around, simplest solution that I found and it works perfect! Having said that, is there are reason why the ListView doesn't simply allow you to set the display field name? I wonder

Comment: Probably because they really want you to supply an object with customized .toString() behavior. Here, you could wrap BluetoothDevice with your own class and make toString do whatever you want. I agree with your OP though, it would be easier to have an overridable getDisplayString method.

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this: (Note: that I havent try it. )

```
public class MyArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Object> {
  public MyArrayAdapter(Context c, List<Object> data){
   super(c, 0, data);
   mData = data;

 }
 @Override
 public Object getItem(int position){
    return ((BluetoothDevice)mData.get(position)).getName();
  }

}
```

Comment: By doing this I cannot use the arrayAdapter as a container of Bluetoothdevices...